# implode(): Invalid arguments passed in error message

Tags: php

I get this error:

> implode(): Invalid arguments passed in error message on line 7

And this is my file:

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $cat   = $_POST['cat'];
    $ads   = $_POST['ads'];
    $key2  = !empty($_POST['keyboard']) ? $_POST['keyboard'] : ''; 

    $key = implode(", ", $key2);
    $tel = new Telegram();
    $notice[] = $tel->AddNew($token, $cat, $ads, $key);
  }
?>
```

So how to fix this ?

**Note:** This question is due to one of the answers to my other question:

[How to insert multiple radio button values with PHP OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404664/how-to-insert-multiple-radio-button-values-with-php-oop)

Comment: well, `$key2` seems to be no array.

Comment: maybe you just meant to use `explode()` instead

Comment: This question is due to one of the answers to my other question:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404664/how-to-insert-multiple-radio-button-values-with-php-oop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $key2 = !empty($_POST['keyboard']) ? $_POST['keyboard'] : array();
```

This solves the error, whatever you're trying to do.